# How to align the contents of card in React-Bootstrap based on the content's height/length?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to align the content of the cards such that when the title of the content is too long, the other details such as the `Created on`, `By` and `View` would be on the same line. I've tried using a fixed height with `min-height` for the title row but I don't think it's a good solution as when the title is shorter, there will be a lot of white/empty space.

I also tried using `flex-grow: 1` on the title but it won't fill up the empty spaces as well.

[image]

```
         <Col>
            <Card 
                className='text-center' 
                style={{
                    height: '100%',
                    padding: '15px', 
                    borderRadius: '20px',
                    boxShadow: '0px 5px 15px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%)'
                }}
            >
                <Row style={{marginBottom: '5px'}}>
                    <Col md={6} style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>
                        <div 
                            className='btn btn-success'}
                            style={{padding: '5px 25px', borderRadius: '50px', cursor: 'default', textTransform: 'capitalize'}}
                        >
                            {bulletin.liveStatus}
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={6} style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>
                        <div className='ellipsis-menu' ref={ref}>
                            <FaIcons.FaEllipsisH onClick={showDropDown} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <div className='view-bulletin-link'>
                    <Card.Img variant='top' src={imageCoverUrl} style={{objectFit: 'cover', height: '15rem', width: '100%', display: 'block'}}/>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title style={{fontSize: '1rem'}}><strong>{bulletin.title}</strong></Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>Created on {moment(bulletin.createdDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")} <br />By {bulletin.createdBy}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text>{bulletin.viewCount > 1 ? <>{bulletin.viewCount} Views</> : <>{bulletin.viewCount} View</>}</Card.Text>
                    </Card.Body>
                </div>
            </Card>
        </Col>
```

[image: Edit beautiful-sun-z0jvt]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with flex.

Card content should have

```
flex-direction: col;
align-items: space-around
```

and wrap the top and bottom aligned elements in different div/spans.

Answer (score -1):

You could group the `created` and `view count` together and make it bottom position.

See example below

```html
<div style="postion:absolute; bottom: 0">
                        <Card.Text>Created on {moment(bulletin.createdDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")} <br />By {bulletin.createdBy}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text>{bulletin.viewCount > 1 ? <>{bulletin.viewCount} Views</> : <>{bulletin.viewCount} View</>}</Card.Text>

</div>
```